# generator for a cyclic group under addition modulo

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Why is the generator for set $\mathbb{Z}_{n}=\left \{ 0,1,...,n-1  \right \}$ $1$ and $-1?$

> The theorem says for a group $G$ to be a cyclic group there must exists an element a in the group G such that 
>   $G=\left \{ a^{n}| n\in \mathbb{Z}\right \}$.

But I am not sure about the 'mechanics' of how to go about finding that a=1 and a=-1 is the generator in this case.

Answer (score 0):

It is not true that the generators of $\mathbb{Z}_n$ are only $1,-1$. In fact, for every $0<a<n$ such that $gcd(a,n)=1$ you will have that $\overline{a}$ generates $\mathbb{Z}_n$.

Since $1$ is clearly a generator of $\mathbb{Z}_n$, then we have that

$$\text{$\overline{a}$ generates $\mathbb{Z}_n$} \Leftrightarrow m\cdot \overline{a}=\overline{1} \text{  for some $m\in\mathbb{Z}$}\Leftrightarrow m\cdot \alpha - 1=k\cdot n \text{  for some $k,m\in\mathbb{Z}$}$$

$$\Leftrightarrow m\cdot a + k\cdot n=1 \text{  for some $k,m\in\mathbb{Z}$}\Leftrightarrow gcd(a,n)=1.$$

A good exercise will be to show that if the cyclic group is infinite, then it has only two generators.